# Process name is not update on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing a program with C# on Visual Studio 2012. I have encountered the following problem.

The first, I configure the assembly name on project C# is "ABC", I built and it generated the executive file is "ABC.exe", then when run this exe on the PC (Windows 8), the Task Manager displays process name is "ABC" => It's ok!

And then, I changed assembly name to "CDE", rebuild and it generate file "CDE.exe".
And when run "CDE.exe" file on above Window 8 PC, the Task Manager displays process name still is "ABC"?

Note that this problem occurs only on the PC run Windows 8. I tested on 2 PC run Windows 7, the process name will update is "CDE.exe".

Someone can tell me what happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is picking up the value of the AssemblyTitleAttribute specified for your executable assembly.

Open up AssemblyInfo.cs, and you should find this line:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ABC")]
```

Change that (and any other attributes in the same file) accordingly.